# SQL calculation on number of tuples involving a composite primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key

Consider the table: **myTable**(**a**,**b**,c,d) Where **a** and **b** make up the primary key.

Would the result of the following query:

```
SELECT distinct(b) FROM myTable;
```

be the same as:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable;
```

In other words, will the result set of the first query have the same amount of tuples as **myTable**? I think no because **b** can have non unique values whereas only the primary key **ab** is unique.

Comment: Yes, you answered your own question

Comment: Thanks, was making sure i didn't misunderstand anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since b is not a primary key for myTable. Consider the case

```
| a | b |
+---+---+
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
```

in the first case, you'll have 2 tuples (and only the column b), while in the second case you'll have 5 tuples and all the column of the tables.